# Flutter make my app default to open json files on android

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to set my app to be the default app so that when a user taps on a file it opens the app and can read it.
Currently I have the functionality that is to select the json file and share it to my app and that is working for me.

```
pubspec.yaml
environment: sdk: ">=3.1.3 <4.0.0" depedencies: receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.5
```

I have declared this in

```
 `AndroidManifest.xml` 
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <data android:mimeType="application/json" /> </intent-filter>
```

With this configuration I can associate my app so that it opens by tapping on json files. But I have 2 behaviors. Yes, I have the json file on WhatsApp. Using the code I already had, I receive this as an argument and I don't know how to read the file. Using the following code I use this code, I use both as a test.

```
ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStreamAsUri().listen((event) { print('gettext stream as uri $event'); });



ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((event) async { print('as string $event dddd'); });
```

I get this result.

`'content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/f49880e7-c89d-48c0-94dc-19a0c896b77e'`

But I don't know how to read it, here I hope to read the json file. But if I open another another app. e.g. telegram. I can't receive anything. the app does not know that the app was opened using a json file. Some kind soul who gives me some light on how to solve it, I would appreciate it, Greeting